# Parse error on explode function

Tags: explode, parse-error, php-parse-error

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' on line 108

```
$row->liked_by = $row->liked_by ? explode('|', $row->liked_by) : [];
```

This is the error i am getting but works fine on the local server. I am trying to run the explode function on hostgator server with PHP 5.3 version.

here's the code for which i am getting this parse error.

```
while($row = $articlesQuery->fetch_object()) {
    $row->liked_by = $row->liked_by ? explode('|', $row->liked_by) : [];
    $articles[] = $row;
}
```

please help

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Short array syntax [`[]`](http://php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php) has support from PHP5.4+

Comment: so how to get this code work in PHP 5.3? bcoz hostgator does not have PHP 5.4 or a higher version

Comment: Just use traditional `array()` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`[]` notation for arrays is only supported in PHP 5.4+, try this if you're using a lower version :

```
while($row = $articlesQuery->fetch_object()) {
    $row->liked_by = $row->liked_by ? explode('|', $row->liked_by) : array();
    $articles[] = $row;
}
```

Comment: Many Thanks @Maxiwheat it worked and I also requested my hosting server company to upgrade PHP to 5.5